# How to create matrix in python of repeating number?

Tags: python, loops, matrix, iterator

I want to:
Create a vector list from 0 to 4, i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] and from that
Create a matrix containing a "tiered list" from 0 to 4, 3 times over, once for each dimension.  The matrix has 4^3 = 64 rows, so for example

```
T = [0 0 0    
       0 0 1  
       0 0 2  
       0 0 3  
       0 0 4  
       0 1 0  
       0 1 1  
       0 1 2  
       0 1 3  
       0 1 4  
       0 2 0  
       ...  
       1 0 0  
       ...  
       1 1 0  
       ....  
       4 4 4]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
n=5;
ind=list(range(0,n))
print(ind)
```

I am just getting started with Python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) `product()` function can do this:

```
for code in itertools.product( range(5), repeat=3 ):
    print(code)
```

Giving the result:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
...
(4, 4, 2)
(4, 4, 3)
(4, 4, 4)
```

So to make this into a matrix:

```
import itertools
matrix = []
for code in itertools.product( range(5), repeat=3 ):
     matrix.append( list(code) )
```

Comment: @Tomothy32 - I had to go lookup the syntax, you beat me to it.  I don't like the "pythonic" way, it's unreadable, especially for a beginner.

Comment: Also, `matrix = [list(code) for code in itertools.product(range(5), repeat=3)]` is easier and more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list_ = []
 for a in range(5):
     for b in range(5):
        for c in range(5):
              list_ += [a ,b ,c ]

 print(list_)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. First, it makes a list that is one dimensional instead of having many rows of 3. Second, what would be the rows are backwards compared to what is asked for.

Comment: The OP mentions matrix in their question but offers up a python list `T = [0 0 0` etc with no commas just newlines and spaces

Answer (score 0):

Note, you really want the matrix to have 5^3 = 125 rows. The basic answer is to just iterate in nested for loops:

```
T = []
for a in range(5):
    for b in range(5):
        for c in range(5):
            T.append([a, b, c])
```

There are other, probably faster, ways of doing this, but for sheer get 'er done velocity, it's hard to beat this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `T.append([a, b, c])`?

Comment: That would make the order backwards compared to what OP is asking for.

Comment: Are you sure? Running it on my machine: `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [4, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0], [4, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [1, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0], [3, 3, 0], [4, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [1, 4, 0], [2, 4, 0], [3, 4, 0], [4, 4, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1], [4, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [4, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1], [1, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1], [0, 4, 1], [1, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1] ...`

Comment: Compare your result carefully with what OP asked for. It was [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2], ... ]

Comment: Exactly, running your solution outputs the wrong result.

Comment: bah. so it does.